# Can't find compiled resource bundles

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4.

I've run into this issue with my latest project, but I was able to re-create it with an almost empty project.
Here is what I've done.

- Created a new Flex Project
- Created a locale/en_US folder within this project.
- Added a class that extends SparkDownloadProgressBar.  All this class does is attempt to create a Label.

When I try to debug this application, I get the following error.

```
Error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'components' for locale 'en_US'.
at mx.resources::ResourceManagerImpl/installCompiledResourceBundle()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\resources\ResourceManagerImpl.as:340]
at mx.resources::ResourceManagerImpl/installCompiledResourceBundles()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\resources\ResourceManagerImpl.as:269]
at mx.resources::ResourceManagerImpl/processInfo()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\resources\ResourceManagerImpl.as:387]
at mx.resources::ResourceManagerImpl()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\resources\ResourceManagerImpl.as:122]
at mx.resources::ResourceManager$/getInstance()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\resources\ResourceManager.as:111]
at mx.core::UIComponent()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:3728]
at spark.components.supportClasses::TextBase()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\TextBase.as:154]
at spark.components::Label()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Label.as:384]
at Preloader()[C:\SVN\Games\Social\Test\src\Preloader.as:21]
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/initialize()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:253]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1925]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2419]
```

The Flex Compiler/Additional Compiler Arguments section does contain "-locale en_US", but I do not want to just remove this as I am planning to have this load different property files based on the localization region at run-time and how I understand it, I will need to add each locale that I am planning to use on the compile argument line.

I am at a loss as to how to attack this problem.  If you need anymore information from me to help with this, I will be more than happy to provide it.  Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue: my Flex 4 web project worked just fine with a custom locale set via compiler options, until I created a custom preloader that extends `SparkDownloadProgressBar`. When that preloader is empty, it works. But it fails as soon as I add a `Label` or an `Image` to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by the fact, that Preloader **loads the actual framework**, so you can't use the Flex's classes until it loads. Use standard TextField for it and it should work fine.